# Add a all integers from a String to another String

Tags: java, int

What is the best way to do this?
Let's say I have a string that is mixed with letters and numbers,

```
Srting str = "ha2iwea435";
String str2 = (str Digits);
```

and I want a string with just the numbers from in between the other letters, or at the end. So my other string would equal the 4th char of str, 2. I suppose I would need to put this in a for loop, and then append a List with the value of str2 so I could assign str2 to 435.
for example,

```
for(int i = 0; str.length() > i; i++){
    str2 = "";
    if(str(char_here(i).isNUMBER()) {
        for(y = i; str(char_here[y]).isNUMBER(); y++) {
          str2 += str.(char_here);
        }
    }
    List1.add(str2);
}
```

I have no idea what methods and tests to use. 
*So in the end, I would have a List that equals ("2", "435")*
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, except instead of a list, you should use a StringBuilder. Why don't you try instead of asking?

Comment: Because I don't know how, and I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Your question is not clear. First you say that you want the number between letters, then the numbers at the end, then all the numbers. You're also talking about the fourth char, which is `i`. Please give us examples of inputs and outputs.

Comment: So in the end, I would have a List with all of the numbers in str. List would equal, ("2", "435")

Comment: Your update is still not clear. Give us input/output examples.

Comment: Ok, hope I made it more clear this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to remove the non-digits characters:

```
String str = "ha2iwea435";
String numbers = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
System.out.println("numbers = " + numbers); //prints 2435
```

If you need each group of numbers in a list you can split on letters and add each group to a list:

```
String str = "ha2iwea435";
String[] numbers = str.split("[^\\d]");

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<> ();
for (String number : numbers) {
    if (!number.isEmpty()) list.add(Integer.parseInt(number));
}
System.out.println("numbers = " + list); // numbers = [2, 435]
```

And if you want to store the numbers as Strings:

```
String str = "ha2iwea435";
String[] numbers = str.split("[^\\d]");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(numbers));
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
System.out.println("numbers = " + list); // numbers = [2, 435]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want ALL the numbers, I need each number from in between the letters, That's why I said it would most likely have to be in a for loop, so I can store the values in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing regex would be the easiest way to get each number and store it in a list.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D+");
String str = "ha2iwea435";
String[] nums = pattern.split(str);

List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String s : nums) 
    values.add(Integer.parseInt(s));

//test
for(int i : values)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "ha2iwea435";
String [] str1=str.replaceAll("[\\D]", "").split("(?<!^)");
```

the str1 will give you the array of numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String str = "ha2iwea435";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d++)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {

        String group = m.group();

        result.add(Integer.parseInt( group)); // result [2,435]
    }
```

The result is a list with 2 and 435